# machine learning classification for noisy data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I need to build a classification algorithm and use it for data that consists of points x={x_1, x_2,..., x_n} where x_1 etc. are themselves experimentally measured quantities and so have posterior distributions.

How should I take this behaviour of the data into account? Should I train the algorithm on noisy data to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you always want to start with the simplest/clean data. That will serve as a point of reference for improvement. Basically, get the famous IRIS dataset and train your algorithm on it. Compare your result with the known IRS dataset accuracy. This should be your starting point.

Comment: Thanks, it's just that I'm planning a study and wanted to estimate its feasibility. So I was hoping to understand how I would treat noisy data in principle, before actually training the classifier.